# Timeago plugin to always be on()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, timeago

How would I change the following code (which makes the timeago plugin work) to use the on() function (or others) so that it can be used live? I can't quite seem to figure it out (I'm fairly new to JQuery).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("a.timeago").timeago();
});
```

How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MutationObserver to check when the DOM was modified: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You pick a node to observe. For your project you should observe the container the `a.timeago` elements will be created into. `<body>` is fine but will incur more work for the browser. Then, whenever the dom changes, a callback will be fired. Catch the elements you care about.

Modified from the documentation:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#your-container');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(addedNode) {
        // if the addedNode matches $('a.timeago')
        //    $(addedNode).timeago();
    });
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```